# Time manipulation in a hardhat test

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Say I have a function in a Solidity smart contract that requires a certain period of time to pass before it will take some action for this example let's say one year and to properly implement a unit test for this function I need to wait one year now obviously that is impractical so my question is: Is there an easy way to manipulate the `block.timestamp` value inside of the hardhat development network?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anybody looking back on this, I found the solution on this stack overflow post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86633/time-dependent-tests-with-hardhat